# How can I show splash screen while the app check a condition in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app I check if there is a user logged in. The problem with me is that even if there is a user logged in, it shows the login page for a while and then jumps to the home page. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure you are doing that initialization before the call to `runApp()`. Declare your `initialRoute` in a variable so you can change it depending if the user is logged in or not.
Also you must call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` to be able to wait until the processing is finished, and declare your `main` method as `async`.

Something like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var initialRoute = 'login';

  var isUserLoggedIn = await User.IsUserLoggedIn();

  if (isUserLoggedIn) {
    initialRoute = 'home';
  }

  runApp(MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  MyApp({@required this.initialRoute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      routes: {
        'login': (context) => LoginPage(),
        'home': (context) => HomePage(),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Everything that happens before the call to `runApp` will be done while the splash is seen.

Comment: It says IsUserLoggedIn is not defined for the type “User”

Comment: I've put that just as an example, of how and where you should make the call. In this case you need to use your own method to validate if the user is logged in. Maybe looking into SharedPreferences or calling Firebase getCurrentUser method. Hope it helps!

Comment: I had to replace MyApp({@required this.initialRoute}); with const MyApp({Key? key, required this.initialRoute}) : super(key: key);
But anyway your solution was helpful